# How to lemmatize a string ndarray in python

Tags: python, nltk, numpy-ndarray, lemmatization

I am using the following code in python to read a dataset for SMS spam/ham. As a usual operation I want to lemmatize the independent variable X before running the model on it
But for that I will need to reassign the values in X which seems impossible and I am getting 
the error `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment` at the line `X[i][j]=lemmatizeSentence(X[i][j])` What approach can I take to make this work.

**My thoughts:** 
There are two things here

1. Why this exception is being thrown. Because normally string reassignment is not an issue if I just do this x = "xyz" x = "lkjsl" This will work here too I am doing the same thing
2. The alternative approach I think is to create a new array X1 and populate data from X after lemmatization in it. But I am not sure on how to go ahead with this approach

   ```
   df = pd.read_excel('spam.xlsx')
   df['Class']=df.Class.map({'ham':0, 'spam':1})
   numpy_array = df.to_numpy()
   print(numpy_array)
   Y=numpy_array[:,0]
   X=numpy_array[:,1]
   Y=Y.astype('int')

   import nltk 

   nltk.download('wordnet')

   w_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()
   lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()

   def lemmatizeSentence(sentence):
       list1 = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in w_tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)]
       return ' '.join(list1)

   for i in range(len(X)):
       for j in range(len(X[i])):
          X[i][j]=lemmatizeSentence(X[i][j])
   ```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to assign to individual characters of a string. What's the shape of X?